# Need Software for small businesses to compute assets expenses cost of good solds and inventory

Tags: accounting

My wife uses https://bukukas.co.id/

to do her stuff.

It has good features. Everytime she buys a bag she put the money in bukukas. If she sells she put the transaction too. She can know what items she has and how much she buy and how much profit per item and stuffs.

It lacks one simple feature.

Say at one time she wants to know the total value of her bags. She got to use calculator and sum it one by one.

I wonder if there is a software like bukukas but with that feature of knowing total assets.

Additional preferences

1. open source is definitely better
2. free is better
3. something that can sync with comp is better
4. The small biz is a simple buy and sell designer bags. So basically buy bags and store them in inventory and sell it again. We don't cook or do anything complicated. I am not sure more general bookkeeping software like quickbook is appropiate

Comment: Hi. Please specify the other features required for the replacement, as others may not know what bukakas does. Also, clarify whether you prefer online, offline, self-hosted, free/commercial system etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can pursue a number of options, including:

- Use one of the opensource ERP systems e.g. [Dolibarr](http://www.dolibarr.org), [ODOO](https://github.com/odoo/odoo), [ERPNext](http://www.erpnext.org). But they have a lot more than you actually require... So you will have to evaluate them and pick the preferred one and limit to modules required.
- The alternative is to get the valuation feature added to your current system, by talking to the developers.
- Commercial systems like QuickBooks will also enable you to do the asset valuation.